# Divide each cell in dataframe by max of of that column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like below and i need to divide each cell by max of its column :

```
Col1  Col2
5      10
20     20
25     30
100    40
```

Output should look like :

```
Col1   Col2
1/20    1/4
1/5     1/2
1/4     3/4
1       1
```

Answer (score 3):

It is as simple as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Col1': [5, 20, 25, 100], 'Col2': [10, 20, 30, 40]})
df / df.max()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

```
df.apply(lambda x: x / x.max())
```

This divides each column by the maximum value found in each column

Answer (score 1):

First, compute the max value per column:

```
max_value = df.max()
```

Now, divide each element of the DataFrame by the max value of the respective column:

```
df = df.div(max_value)
```